# Trouble passing vote variable to js - I'm not using forms, POST, or django-voting

Tags: javascript, django, vote

I have a simple entry and display system for short texts on a single web page. The text input is just an input field with a GET in views. I'd like a very basic up or down voting system on the page for the latest entries. I can get the latest entries into a variable...

Some people online have hinted that a variable can be passed to the js, and this is my first port of call before anything further.

I have not used forms or POST yet, as it seems to include urls and code unnecessary to my basic needs. Can anyone advise me on how I can pass my variable to js?

Here's some snippets of code;

**template**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
{% for entry in voting_entry %}
    var votingEntry="{{entry.id}}"         
    {% endfor %}     
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}vote.js"></script>
```

**vote.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#votingEntry").bind("keypress", function(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        var vote = $("#votingEntry").val();     
        var args = {'vote':vote};           
        $.get("/vote/", args).done(function(data) {
        location.reload();  
      });
    }   
  });
```

**views**

```
def index(request):
  context = {
  'latest_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10],
  'high_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-score')[:10],
  'low_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('score')[:10],
  'voting_entry': Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1],
  }
   return render(request, 'entries/index.html', context);

*snip*

def vote(request):
  voting_id = request.GET.get('vote')
  v = Entry.objects.get(pk='voting_id')
  v.score +=1
  v.save()       
  return HttpResponse('votedone')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it with a very simple form in template. The submit buttons trigger a views.vote function by url, the views.vote detects up or down button names, and saves a vote to the entry referenced by entryid. This is brought in by a POST.get on the hidden name in the template form.

Lastly, a redirect keeps it all on one page and refreshes the index.

**template**

```
<ul>
{% for entry in voting_entry_list %}
    <li><a href="/entries/{{ entry.id }}/">{{ entry.text }}{{ entry.score }}</a></li>
    <li><form method="POST" action="/vote/" >
    {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="voteid" value="{{ entry.id }}" />
      <input type="submit" name='voteup' value="Up" />
      <input type="submit" name='votedown' value="Down" />
    </form><li>  
{% endfor %}  
</ul>
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^index/$', 'entries.views.index'),
  url(r'^add/$', 'entries.views.add'),
  url(r'^vote/$', 'entries.views.vote')
)
```

**views**

```
@csrf_protect  
def vote(request):
 voting_id = request.POST.get('voteid',None)
 if request.method=='POST':
   if 'voteup' in request.POST:
     v = Entry.objects.get(pk=voting_id)
     v.score +=1
     v.save()
   if 'votedown' in request.POST:
     v = Entry.objects.get(pk=voting_id)
     v.score -=1
     v.save()
 else:
    pass
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/index')
```

My final issue was having to take the quotes off the - pk=voting_id - to prevent an error of "invalid literal for int() with base 10".

Hope this helps someone else who just wants to start with these systems in a basic manner, but something not quite the same as the django polls tutorials. It was a bit tough wading through the various methods of doing it (JSON, js, POST, forms, regex, urls, etc.), so here is the way I did it with various snippets from many SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do. In the first snippet you repeatedly set the same variable, `votingEntry`, to a string containing an ID from a list. Since you set the same variable each time, the var will end up with only the last value from the list.

Additionally, in order to set a global variable *outside* a function in JS, you need the `var` keyword.

However, I'm not quite sure why you are doing any of this, because you're then not using the `votingEntry` variable anywhere else in your JS. You need to provide more detail about what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,....Your confusion is due to the fact that I don't really know what I am doing. What I hope to achieve is to have the user vote on a text object presented to them (the latest entered).

All the texts are entered into an sqlite3 database that has text, score and date entered. All this code works fine. 

I was just trying to do a simple voting system based off that. Other voting examples in django and js seemed overly complicated, so I'm trying to keep it simple and pass the id of the latest to views for a score change when I press a key (up arrow).

Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi - edit has clarified I am not setting more that one var in template...not sure what you mean about this bit though; "Additionally, in order to set a global variable outside a function in JS, you need the var keyword."

Comment: no one pointed this out, but for a start have changed the template code  to this;

   <script type="text/javascript">
    {% for entry in voting_entry_list %}
    votingEntry="{{entry.id}}"         
    {% endfor %}     
</script>

I'll let you know if I manage to get it working....

Comment: You're still setting the same variable over and over again in your loop. And you need to use the JavaScript `var` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, actually I had changed that as well. Updated template above. Still no luck ................................As for the setting the variable over and over in the loop; the voting_entry_list has only one value (in view), and that gets updated according to the latest entry, so the for loop checks for that, unless you have a suggestion........................Either way, the value still doesn't get passed. Should the code I have pass the value, or is it broken?